# partial derivations and evaluation commute?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function in three variables.
I am trying to figure out taking derivative with respect to $x$ or $y$ commute with setting $z = 0$?
In other words does
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x, y, 0) = \frac{ \partial F(\cdot, \cdot, 0) }{\partial x} (x, y)
$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$? I have tried some examples and they all seem to  satisfy this.. Any comments appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, just write out the definitions:$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,0):=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{F(x+t,y,0)-F(x,y,0)}{t}=:\frac{\partial F(\cdot,\cdot,0)}{\partial x}(x,y)$$